# How to sort files from a directory by date in java?

Tags: java, file, sorting, date

I have a method which reads the content from files located in a directory. But for functional reasons it is necessary to start with the oldest file (indicated by the property lastmodified) and end with the newest file.

This is the code how I open and read the files:

```
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.matches("access_log.*");
        }
    };

    File folder = new File("/home/myfiles");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        String sFileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        File accessLogFile = new File(aLog.getPath(), sFileName);
        long time=accessLogFile.lastModified();
        // do something with the file
    }
```

Has anybody a solution how I can quickly sort my list of files by date?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified contain the answer to your question?

Comment: Have you tried FileUtils.dirListByAscendingDate? http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0606.html

Comment: You seem to be interested in log files. These are often named in a way such that lexical sorting by file name also sorts by time.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Java 8

```
public static void sortOldestFilesFirst(File[] files) {
    Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified));
}

public static void sortNewestFilesFirst(File[] files) {
    Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
}
```

#### Java 7

```
public static void sortOldestFilesFirst(File[] files) {
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File a, File b) {
            return Long.compare(a.lastModified(), b.lastModified());
        }
    });
}

public static void sortNewestFilesFirst(File[] files) {
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File a, File b) {
            return Long.compare(b.lastModified(), a.lastModified());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi you could generify this which would mean you could remove the casting in the compare method: Arrays.sort( files, new Comparator<File>(){...})

Comment: Thanks, dude! it still works!

Comment: You made my day :) Thank you.

Comment: @PratikButani Glad you found it useful :)

Comment: what is the use of -1, 1 and 0?

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to use a comparator. There is a similar question and answer here... 
[Best way to list files in Java, sorted by Date Modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified)

Answer (score 0):

I would use FileUtils in [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/) to get back the Collection of Files. I would then apply a custom comparator. It should be pretty easy.