# How to sort alphabetically while ignoring case sensitive?

Tags: java, android, collections

I have this code, but works only for lower case letters.  I want this to sort the list while ignoring the upper case letters..

```
package sortarray.com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SortArray extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String[]> matchedFruits = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    TextView selection;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String fruits[] = new String[7];// Sorted array
        fruits[0] = "apple";
        fruits[1] = "apricot";
        fruits[2] = "banana";
        fruits[3] = "mango";
        fruits[4] = "melon";
        fruits[5] = "pineapple";
        fruits[6] = "peach";
        char currChar = fruits[0].charAt(0);// Get first char of first element

        boolean match = false;
        int len = fruits.length;
        List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            Log.d("Comparing ", fruits[i].charAt(0) + "," + currChar);
            if (fruits[i].charAt(0) == currChar) {
                if (match == false)// new match?
                {
                    match = true;// Reset search
                    tmp.clear();// clear existing items
                    tmp.add(fruits[i - 1]);
                    Log.d("Started new list ", fruits[i - 1]);
                } else {
                    tmp.add(fruits[i - 1]);
                    Log.d("Added to list ", fruits[i - 1]);
                }
            } else {
                match = false;
                tmp.add(fruits[i - 1]);
                matchedFruits.add(tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]));// add to
                                                                        // final
                                                                        // list
                Log.d("Finished a list ", fruits[i - 1]);
                tmp.clear();// clear existing items

            }
            currChar = fruits[i].charAt(0);

        }
        tmp.add(fruits[len - 1]);
        matchedFruits.add(tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()]));// add left over
                                                                // items
        printList();
    }

    void printList()
    {
    //Print the list 
        TextView selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        String mssg="";
    for(int i=0;i<matchedFruits.size();i++)
    {
            String tmp2[]= matchedFruits.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < tmp2.length; j++) {
                //Log.d("Final list", "Array #" + i + "[" + j + "]," + tmp2[j]);
                mssg += tmp2[j].toString();

            }
            //selection.setText("\n");
            selection.setText(mssg);

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don´t you use sort() or sth. like that for arrays or collections?

Comment: @jitender: What do you want to do, would you elaborate..?

Comment: i want to sort a list in dictionary order while ignoring the case sensitive letters...i.e if i write man and Mango they come together in the list after sorting.

Comment: I think jitender is looking for a *natural sort* order and I have no idea why [Collections.sort](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List<T>)) isn't being used!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a plain java example of the best way to do it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorter {
    String fruits[] = new String[7];
    List<String> lst;

    Sorter() {
        lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        // initialise UNSORTED array
        fruits[0] = "Melon"; fruits[1] = "apricot"; fruits[2] = "peach";
        fruits[3] = "mango"; fruits[4] = "Apple";   fruits[5] = "pineapple";
        fruits[6] = "banana";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sorter srt = new Sorter();
        srt.anyOldUnstaticMethod();

    }
    public void anyOldUnstaticMethod() {
        Collections.addAll(lst, fruits);
        System.out.println("Initial List");
        for (String s : lst)
            System.out.println(s);
        Collections.sort(lst);
        System.out.println("\nSorted List");
        for (String s : lst)
            System.out.println(s);
        Collections.sort(lst, new SortIgnoreCase());
        System.out.println("\nSorted Ignoring Case List");
        for (String s : lst)
            System.out.println(s);
    }

    public class SortIgnoreCase implements Comparator<Object> {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            String s1 = (String) o1;
            String s2 = (String) o2;
            return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified

Comment: This is so much more complicated that it needs to be.

Answer (score 194):

```
Collections.sort(listToSort, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: you don't have to create your own case-insensitive String Comparator, just use String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER (since Java 1.2)

Comment: And what if I want to pass two properties, like insensitive order AND reverse order?

Comment: Worth noting that this will modify the existing list so the list needs to be mutable.

Comment: You can also write: theList.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

Comment: For sorting an arraylist of objects, we do need to write a comparator

Answer (score 48):

It is **very** unclear what you are trying to do, but you can sort a list like this:

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>(7);

fruits.add("Pineapple");
fruits.add("apple");
fruits.add("apricot");
fruits.add("Banana");
fruits.add("mango");
fruits.add("melon");        
fruits.add("peach");

System.out.println("Unsorted: " + fruits);

Collections.sort(fruits, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {              
        return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
    }
});

System.out.println("Sorted: " + fruits);
```

Answer (score 40):

`Collections.sort()` lets you pass a custom comparator for ordering. For case insensitive ordering `String` class provides a static final comparator called `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`.

So in your case all that's needed is:

```
Collections.sort(caps, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 17):

I can't believe no one made a reference to the [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/collationintro.html). Almost all of these answers will only work for the English language.

You should almost always use a [Collator for dictionary based sorting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

For case insensitive collator searching for the English language you do the following:

```
Collator usCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
usCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
Collections.sort(listToSort, usCollator);
```

Comment: or even shorter: `listToSort.sort(usCollator);`

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 8 you can sort using the Streams API:

```
List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("apple", "Apricot", "banana");

List<String> sortedFruit = fruits.stream()
      .sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The difference with `Collections.sort` is that this will return a new list and will not modify the existing one.

Answer (score 5):

I like the comparator class `SortIgnoreCase`, but would have used this

```
public class SortIgnoreCase implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);    // Cleaner :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the <String> type in the diamond operator to avoid casting to String ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy No reason, other than I didn't think of that or see that at the time maybe... would have been better.

Comment: java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSTIVE_ORDER is predefined. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

Answer (score 5):

You can directly call the default [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method on the list like this:

```
myList.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // reads as the problem statement and cleaner
```

or:

```
myList.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase);  // reads as the problem statement and cleaner
```

Answer (score 5):

Array Sorting in Java 8 Way-> Easy peasy lemon squeezy

```
String[] names = {"Alexis", "Tim", "Kyleen", "KRISTY"};

  Arrays.sort(names, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

I used method Reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 4):

Pass `java.text.Collator.getInstance()` to `Collections.sort` method ; it will sort Alphabetically while ignoring case sensitive.

```
        ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        myArray.add("zzz");
        myArray.add("xxx");
        myArray.add("Aaa");
        myArray.add("bb");
        myArray.add("BB");
        Collections.sort(myArray,Collator.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your comparator factory class, do something like this:

```
 private static final Comparator<String> MYSTRING_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
      return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
  };

  public static Comparator<String> getMyStringComparator() {
    return MYSTRING_COMPARATOR;
```

This uses the compare to method which is case insensitive (why write your own). This way you can use Collections sort like this:

```
List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
//fill your array here    
Collections.sort(MyArray, MyComparators. getMyStringComparator());
```

Answer (score 2):

We can pass both the field and the caseInsensitivitive in Comparator

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Ticket::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried converting the first char of the string to lowercase on `if(fruits[i].charAt(0) == currChar)` and `char currChar = fruits[0].charAt(0)` statements?

Answer (score 0):

**Example using Collections and ArrayList:**

Develop an intern static class like the example "CompareStrings".

Call the intern static class in the main method.

Easy to understand and works fine!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        myArray.add("zzz");
        myArray.add("xxx");
        myArray.add("Aaa");
        myArray.add("bb");
        myArray.add("BB");
        Collections.sort(myArray, new MainClass.CompareStrings());
        for(String s : myArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static class CompareStrings implements Comparator<String> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
           return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have a `List` of Strings and most of the already proposed solutions (I specially like @guyblank answer) are just fine but!!!, if you have a `List` of beans, which is my case, you can use `Comparable` interface in your bean like this:

```
public class UserBean implements Comparable<UserBean> {

   private String name;
   private String surname;        
   private Integer phone;

   // GETTERS AND SETTERS

   public int compareTo(UserBean bean) {
       return name.compareToIgnoreCase(bean.name);
   }

}
```

Then you only need to create your `ArrayList<UserBean> userBeanArray = new ArrayList<UserBean>();`, fill it and sort it: `Collections.sort(userBeanArray);`

And you have it done!

Hope to help to community ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example to sort an array : Case-insensitive

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String[] myArray = new String[] { "A", "B", "b" };
    Arrays.sort(myArray, Collator.getInstance());

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));

 }

}
```

/* Output:[A, b, B] */