# single string list- alphabetizing

Tags: java, string, sorting, alphabetical

I'm trying to write a code that uses a scanner to input a list of words, all in one string, then alphabetizer each individual word. What I'm getting is just the first word alphabetized by letter, how can i fix this?

the code:

```
else if(answer.equals("new"))
    {
      System.out.println("Enter words, separated by commas and spaces.");
      String input= scanner.next();
      char[] words= input.toCharArray(); 
      Arrays.sort(words);
      String sorted= new String(words);
      System.out.println(sorted);

    }
```

**Result:** " ,ahy "

Answer (score 0):

You're reading in a String via `scanner.next()` and then breaking that String up into characters.  So, as you said, it's sorting the single-string by characters via `input.toCharArray()`.  What you need to do is read in all of the words and add them to a `String []`.  After all of the words have been added, use `Arrays.sort(yourStringArray)` to sort them.  See comments for answers to your following questions.

Comment: SO how would i set up the String[]?

Comment: String[] words= (input1, input 2, input 3..) or?

Comment: Yes, create a `String []` and add your strings to that string. Then sort based off of that array.  You can add simply by doing something like `String [] ra= new String[10];` 10 was arbitrary.  You can then add like so: `ra[0]="steve"; ra[1]="hello";`... If you keep track of your size, you can add to the next open slot in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split your string into words instead of characters. One option is using [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). Afterwards, you can join those words back into a single string:

```
System.out.println("Enter words, separated by commas and spaces.");
String input = scanner.nextLine();

String[] words = input.split(",| ");
Arrays.sort(words);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(words[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(words[i]);
}
String sorted = sb.toString();

System.out.println(sorted);
```

Note that by default, capital letters are sorted before lowercase. If that's a problem, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469643/how-to-sort-alphabetically-while-ignoring-case-sensitive).

Comment: something about this isnt computing right, it's compiling but nothing prints out at the end

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe there's a problem with your surrounding code? [Here](http://pastebin.com/3Dze5if9) is a stand-alone example for you to try, to demonstrate it does work.