# Array List of String Sorting Method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i have an Array List with Following values

```
ArrayList [Admin,Readonly,CSR,adminuser,user,customer]
```

when i used

```
Collections.sort(ArrayList)
```

i'm getting the Following Result

```
[Admin,CSR,Readonly,adminuser,customer,user]
```

as per the Java doc the above results are correct, but my Expectation is (sorting irrespective of case (upper / lower case)

```
[Admin,adminuser,CSR,customer,Readonly,user]
```

provide an help how will do the sorting irrespective of case in java, is there any other method available

Note: i will do an Automate test for checking the sorting order in the Web table

regards

prabu

Comment: take a look at java [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: Have you tried this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469643/how-to-sort-alphabetically-while-ignoring-case-sensitive

Comment: Just add a comparator to Collections.sort() which will ignore the case. You could write your own, but there is one already defined in String class: String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER. So you sort call will be "Collections.sort(your_List<String>, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)". The full solution is described by Ulaga below.

Answer (score 7):

This'll do,

```
Collections.sort(yourList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

this is i have tried,

```
ArrayList<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(myList,"Admin","Readonly","CSR","adminuser","user","customer");
System.out.println(myList);
Collections.sort(myList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
System.out.println(myList);
```

the following output i got,

```
[Admin, Readonly, CSR, adminuser, user, customer]
[Admin, adminuser, CSR, customer, Readonly, user]
```

Comment: Collections.sort(before_fn, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
  for (String temp : before_fn) {
   System.out.println("Ascending Order" + temp);
  } its working correctly, let me know the Reversse Order for that same <br/> when i tried Collections.sort(before_fn, Collections.reverseOrder()); its working i required irrespective of case

Answer (score 4):

You can use your own comparator like this to sort irrespective of case (upper / lower case)

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {    
            return  s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with custom Comparator.

Try this:

```
    // list containing String objects
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // call sort() with list and Comparator which
    // compares String objects ignoring case
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        }
    });
```

You will need to pass `Comparator` instance in `Collections.sort()` method which compares `String` objects ignoring case.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SortIgnoreCase implements Comparator<Object> {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String s1 = (String) o1;
        String s2 = (String) o2;
        return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

then

```
Collections.sort(ArrayList, new SortIgnoreCase());
```

Comment: Not sure why you would do Comparator<Object> instead of Comparator<String> when you explicitly typecase them immediately after entering the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(ArrayList, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple - big letters have lower number in `ASCII`. So default comparing works fine.