# Making Collections.binarySearch() work with compareToIgnoreCase?

Tags: java, string, collections, binary-search

So I am searching a huge ArrayList for a particular String value, but I need Collections.binarySearch() to return a value >=0 if the String I am looking for is equal( non case-sensitive) to the String I pass into the binarySearch() method.

Now in the source code for Collections.binarySearch(), it eventually calls the following lines of code.

```
 Comparable<? super T> midVal = list.get(mid);
 int cmp = midVal.compareTo(key);
```

So seen as I cannot override String as its final (therefore preventing me from overriding its compareTo() method to call compareToIgnoreCase() ), is there any other I can achieve this?

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To perform case-insensitive binary search, use `String::compareToIgnoreCase` as a comparator:

```
int i = Collections.binarySearch(list, key, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

This will perform faster than comparing two strings reduced to the same case, because `compareToIgnoreCase()` compares chars one by one, reducing case of chars only if needed, which allows to return fast if strings are different in first chars.

*NB:* To make `binarySearch()` with this comparator work properly, collection **must be sorted using exactly the same comparator**:

```
Collections.sort(list, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Yes. Also note that in order for this to work, the list must have been sorted using the same comparator.

Comment: This is for Java 8 though. This is how you do it in Java 7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17491652/900394

Answer (score 1):

Use an external Comparator, because `java.util.Collections` has a `binarySearch` method with this signature:

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Your comparator would look something like

```
public class CaseInsensitiveComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
      // check if any of the arguments are null, otherwise
      return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Even if you could extend String to override the `compareTo` method, I do not think that would be a good idea.