# Array list sorting in Java

Tags: java

An array list contains some data that needs to be sorted.

```
Data:
A1
A5
B1
A7
B3
```

After sort I need to be shown like below

```
A1
A5
A7
B1
B3
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Help with what?

Comment: What should it be sorted by?

Comment: Need to be sort those series using arraylist

Comment: @maroun Making down votes does not make any sense guys

Comment: @Boopathi It actually makes a lot of sense. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) what kind of questions you should ask here. Also please try to learn from downvotes, they are here to let you know that you can improve your post.

Comment: please see this, here is solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/7470230/938120

Comment: Uh, `Collections.sort(data);` ...?

Comment: @NickBell collection.sort() will help but i  need to sort construtive of number and alphabets

Comment: Any source code you could provide? We will not code this for you but help you with your source code. So how far did you come?

Comment: @Boopathi, Please update your question i.e. sort construtive of number and alphabets.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A1");
list.add("A5");
list.add("B1");
list.add("A7");
list.add("B3");
Collections.sort(list);//For ascending order
Collections.reverse(list);//For descending order
```

Also if you want to sort any custom object then check below link for implementation of comparable/comparator:
http://www.journaldev.com/780/comparable-and-comparator-in-java-example

Answer (score 0):

If your data is just String data, then you can simply use the following piece of code:

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("A1", "A5", "B1", "A7", "B3");
Collections.sort(data);
```

Otherwise, you will need to write a custom logic to sort it.

Refer to this documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom comparator like this:-

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` method of `java.util.Collections` class. You can define your own `Comparator`. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-a-list-arraylist-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top).