# Deleting file from sdcard in android

Tags: android, file, sd-card, delete-file

I am making an app in which I have to delete the recently added mp3 file in sdcard. The format in which the song is saved is:

```
Songhello_17_26.amr
```

where **17_26** is the time when song was added. Can anyone help me how delete the recently added file in sdcard. I mean to say that I want to delete the time means the latest added file should get deleted.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified), you cant do that directly, you first need to get list of files `File.listFiles()`, `Comparator`,`File.lastModified()`, `Arrays.sort()` and delete.

Edited:

```
File f = new File(path);

File [] files = f.listFiles();

Arrays.sort( files, new Comparator()
{
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
            return +1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

});
```

To delete latest one:

```
 files[0].delete();
```

Comment: Your link was very good but can you please help me with proper sample code.Your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: With the help of your code i am able to get list of all mp3 files now can you please tell me how to delete latest entry

Comment: Hotveryspicy , i am also stuck at same problem and i am also eagerly waiting for your answere means with the help of your code i got all files from sdcard now how to delete the latest entry?

Comment: File file = new File(files[o]);
   file.delete();

Comment: Can you please edit your new answere File file = new File(files[o]); file.delete(); in above  answere

Comment: you can see, if its not delete the latest file then sort collection reverse order and then delete.

Comment: I have made file name hello as updated in your answere now can you please guide me how to get first element in that file

Comment: you can do like this files[0].delete(); directly.

Comment: As this answer is also mentioned in another question I've contributed allow me to be critic: Do you really think it's necessary to sort the Array to find the most recent file? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11482771/1063730 I believe traversing through the array once and just holding the most recent item should be more efficient, prove me wrong? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  public String[] getDirectoryList(String path) {
     String[] dirListing = null;
     File dir = new File(path);
     dirListing = dir.list();

     Arrays.sort(dirListing, 0, dirListing.length);
     return dirListing;
  }

  String[]  lstFile = getDirectoryList()
 if(lstFile.length > 0){
    File file = new File(lstFile[0]);
    boolean fStatus = file.delete();

  }
```

Comment: I just gave  this as example but i have dynamic files and i dont know the name , i want to delete file by time means latest entry should get deleted

Comment: I accept @hotveryspicy suggestion . `File.listFiles(), Comparator,File.lastModified(), Arrays.sort()` this have to do

Answer (score 2):

**try this method :

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if( path.exists() ) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    enter code here        if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                deleteDirectory(files[i]);
            }
            else {
                files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }
    return(path.delete());
}
```

or you can use the following code to delete the file from sd-card:

`File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String fileName = folder.getPath() + "/pass/hello.pdf";`
with

```
 String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pass/hello.pdf";**
```

Answer (score 0):

try this too:

```
  String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 File file = new File(path) ;       
  File list[] = file.listFiles();
    for(File f:list)
      {
     name =  file.getName();
    filestv.setText(f.getName());
    //add new files name in the list
   //  delete.setText(name );
```

that code you can see the latest file saved in sdcard, i suggest you to follow along this [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/06/delete-latest-file-from-any-specific.html).