# How to delete the latest file from any specific folder in sdcard in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am creating a camera application.Through this I am able to capture the image and storing it into a specific folder.but during this process,the image is getting stored in its default position say **sdcard/DCIM/CAMERA**.

The file name is current date.when user clicks on save button,then the current date is taken and the filename is generated.So i am not able to detect the file name.

**can anybody suggest me that how to access the file name OR how to delete the latest image file programatically.**

Comment: the file name is what? give an eg

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191015/deleting-file-from-sdcard-in-android

Comment: Hi Vinay. the file which gets stored in the default folder is  **2012-07-14 15.08.42.jpg**. which is nothing but the date. But in my specific folder,the file name is **20120714030834.jpg**

Comment: Are you sending an Intent to the Camera app using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in your application or are you using a custom camera with a callback?

Comment: thanks shalini.gr8 link you provided. thanks a lot. +1 for the link..

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is rename new image file with current date based name.You can use this code for rename your files; Immediately, after save file.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard,"from.jpg");
File to = new File(sdcard,"to.jpg");
from.renameTo(to);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to retrieve **all** files as `File` objects from the directory to work on. Starting from there use this method to retrieve the last modified file:

```
public static File getLastModifiedFile( File[] allFiles ) [
    File result = allFiles[1];
    //you cou also use result = null and uncomment the
    //other if-statement. It's probably the first idea but in that case you might
    //return null while here you'll get an exception which makes debugging easier :)

    for( int i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++ ) {
        if( result.lastModified() < allFiles[i].lastModified() ) {
        //if( result == null || result.lastModified() < allFiles[i].lastModified() ) {
            result = currentFile;
        }
    ]
    return result;
}
```

Have a look at the [File documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html). Here you'll find the explenation of `lastModified()`.