# How to get the latest file from a directory using groovy?

Tags: file, groovy

I have a directory that contains a list of files. I wanted to get the latest file out of all the contents of the said directory. How will I do that?

I am using this code, but I am not getting the latest file out of it. Please help.

```
def fileDir = new File("A/B").listFiles().first()
```

Thanks.

Comment: there is a similar question on how to do that in java. you can use that in groovy too and propably simplify it a bit... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As simple as:

```
new File( 'A/B' ).listFiles()?.sort { -it.lastModified() }?.head()
```

(taking the negative lastModified, as we want the newest file first)

Comment: While using this my fileDir is = null. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RodKimble not sure what you mean...  maybe a new question?