# how to sort all the file according to size in directory in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Hi this is a small example to show the

1. How to read all files from DIRECTORY
2. And sort them according to size(ascending and descending order)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13285253/6509

Comment: Do you require a list of sorted files or just traverse the files in directory in a sorted manner?

Answer (score 3):

Here You go:

```
new File('/tmp').listFiles().findAll { it.isFile() }.sort { it.length() }
```