# Deleting all but the last 3 modified files in a directory

Tags: java, android, delete-file

I have a directory of backups saved on the phone, but I can't work out the logic to remove all but the last three.

As it stands I have:

```
public static void checkLocalBackup(){

            String path = Global.backupSingleLocalLocation;
            Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
            File f = new File(path);        
            File file[] = f.listFiles();
            for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
            {
                Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].lastModified());
                //sudo code 
                if(isNotInLastThreeFiles){
                    deleteFile(file[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

This loops through and lists all the last modified files, but I cant work out how to select the oldest files and leave the newest 3?

Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Store all of the `File` objects in a `List<File>` and sort them using a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) so that they are ordered by "lastModified".

Finally, select the last three items from the list (or the first three, depending upon your sort order).

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your files array by modified date:

```
File[] files = folder.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This post shows how to list files by modified date; once you do that, you can easily find the last three:

[Best way to list files in Java, sorted by Date Modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using Comparator you can easily achieve your requirement for getting the last three modified files in your desired directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
       // delete all except 10 latest files
        deleteAllExcept(10);      

  private static void deleteAllExcept(int i) {
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

        for(File file : new File(path_to_folder).listFiles()) {
            files.add(file);
            System.out.println(file.getName());      
        }       
        
        files.stream()
        .filter((File p) -> p.getName().contains("."))
        .sorted(getReverseLastModifiedComparator())
        .skip(i)
        .forEach(x -> ((File) x).delete());
    }
    
    private static Comparator<File> getReverseLastModifiedComparator() {
        return (File o1, File o2) -> {
            if (o1.lastModified() < o2.lastModified()) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified()) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        };
    }
```