# Zipping files in java based on modifed time

Tags: java

```
package codes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.acl.LastOwnerException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ModifyAndDelete 
{
private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "C:\\Users\\s13w63\\Desktop\\Zip";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    File dir = new File(FOLDER_PATH);

    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() 
    {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName)
        {
            if (fileName.endsWith(".INC")) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

    for(File f:files)
    {
        String month=sdf.format(f.lastModified());

        final int lastModifiedMonth=Integer.parseInt(month);        
    }       

    }       
}
```

This is to get the month of the file in which it is modified lastly. Now I want to get the files in a list according to month. How to get the files according to month and I need list for each month. Please help me out guys...

I am using the below code to add and iterate using a hashmap, but It was listing only one file for each month.

```
Map<Integer, List<File>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<File>>();

    for (File f : files) {
        String month = sdf.format(f.lastModified());

        final int lastModifiedMonth = Integer.parseInt(month);

        map.put(lastModifiedMonth, new ArrayList<File>());

        map.get(lastModifiedMonth).add(f);
    }

    for (Entry<Integer, List<File>> entry : map.entrySet()) 
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: And you have tried... What, exactly? Also, do you use Java 7? Java 8? When you have that list of months, what after that?

Comment: Yeah I used switch case based on the last modified month but I am unable to list them according to month

Comment: Also, `.listFiles()` may return null, and you don't check for that

Comment: Yeah first how to separate the files according to month

Comment: You still didn't answer my question; do you use Java 7, Java 8? If not Java 8, can you at least use a sane date/time library?

Comment: Currently I am using Java 7

Comment: Just by month, ignoring the year? 1/2015 and 1/2014 and 1/2013...?

Comment: Yeah I just need monthly wise

Comment: a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (key: month, value: `List` of `File`s) or a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) might do the job

Comment: but map is a unique key and pair combination right, How can we get many values for one key

Comment: One might even consider a `List<File>[]`

Comment: `Map<Integer,List<File>>`

Comment: Yes but how to list the files can you explain it

Comment: You iterate a List and print whatever: for( File f: filelist ){...}

Comment: Yeah I am using for each loop to iterate but once I got that month, how to proceed next

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4248059/180100) use also a clever way to do something similar

Comment: This is 2015 and you use Java 7+; use java.nio.file. Please. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
Map<Integer, List<File>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(File f:files)
{
    String month=sdf.format(f.lastModified());
    final int lastModifiedMonth=Integer.parseInt(month);        
    if (!map.containsKey(lastModifiedMonth)) {
        map.put(lastModifiedMonth, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    map.get(lastModifiedMonth).add(f);
}       
// use map
```

*(typed here, so might not compile)*

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java 7, at least [use `java.nio.file`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API). `File` is terminally broken (note that [`.listFiles()` can return `null`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks#Listing_files_in_a_directory.2C_oh_my) and you don't even check for this).

Sorting by months is easy enough... Code:

```
final Map<Integer, List<Path>> filesByMonths = new HashMap<>();

final Calendar cal = new Calendar();

final Path dir = Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH);

final DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream 
    = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.INC");

List<Path> list;
int month;

for (final Path entry: dir) {
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Files.getLastModifiedTime(entry).toMillis());
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    list = filesByMonth.get(month);
    if (list == null)
        filesByMonth.put(month, list = new ArrayList<>());
    list.add(entry);
}
```

You may also want to use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap` if you want to iterate by month.

As to creating the zips, well you didn't tell, but then with Java 7 you can manipuate a zip as a FileSystem (see the link I posted above, it provides an example). In fact you could create by advance ALL FileSystems to all zips and just copy the files directly into them, no need at all to go through an intermediate map.