# Sorting files quickly based on lastModification time

Tags: java, file, sorting, timestamp

I want to sort files in java based on last modification time. But it should be lightning quick.

```java
File[] fileList = null;

try {
    File rootFolder = new File(dir);

    if (rootFolder.isDirectory()) {
        fileList = rootFolder.listFiles();
    }



Arrays.sort(fileList, new Comparator<File>() {
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
    }
});
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Not a valid directory " + dir);
}
```

Comment: Your code is not doing any sorting. Please [edit] it and add what you have tried. Does it work? Is it fast? How do you measure?

Comment: I would use [NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) for that. [Here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.nio.file.Files&method=walkFileTree) are some good examples just for start...

Comment: @Lutz Horn .... Done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
code from [Sorting files Program](https://www.javacodex.com/More-Examples/1/1)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ListFilesByDate {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      File dir = new File("/tmp/code");
      File[] files = dir.listFiles();
      Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
          return Long.valueOf(f2.lastModified()).compareTo(f1.lastModified());
        } 
      });

      for(File file: files) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should quote that the code has been copied from https://www.javacodex.com/More-Examples/1/1

Comment: Updated, Thanks @f_puras